# Modify script to remove else from condition

Tags: unix, grep, aix

I am trying to find a few key words from one file using while loop and checking in another if they are present or not. If not they should be written in another file.
Below is my code

```
while read -r line; do
if grep -q -e "$line" $file_name; then
        echo "character found"
else
    echo "$line" >> notfound.txt
fi  
done  < result.txt`
```

I feel that the whole if condition can be simplified by excluding the else part and also the echo "character found" as there are a lot of characters. Please help in removing this. I tried -v but unfortunately didn't work.

Also is it possible for using while loop starting from maybe the 3rd line and end 2 lines before

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample input files and the desired output: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it can be done in a single line, by checking the return-code of the command as it is executed, see [bash, exit-codes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do

   # On successful search 'grep' returns code '0', negating it for the
   # unsuccessful case to return a 'true' condition

   ! grep -q -e "$line" "$file_name"  && echo "$line" >> notfound.txt

done <result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget it; use comm(1) that's what it is good for. Example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

cat >needles <<DONE
p1
n1
p2
n2
DONE

cat >haystack <<DONE
p3
p2
p1
DONE

comm -23 <(sort -u needles) <(sort -u haystack)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$filename` is an arbitrary text file, and `result.txt` is a file containing a list of words, one per line.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# 1. get the list of words found in the file, store in an array
mapfile -t found < <(grep -owFf result.txt "$filename" | sort -u)

# 2. get the list of words not found
grep -vxFf <(printf "%s\n" "${found[@]}") result.txt
```